# calling java script return value to code page in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i want to call my java script function  return value to my code
i have a function like this..(this i wrote in my java script)

```
function GetSex()
{

    var sex = EIDAWebComponent.GetSex();
    if(sex == 'M')
        return "Male";
    if(sex == 'F')
        return "Female";
    if(sex == 'X')
        return "Unknown";
}
```

my code:

```
<td>
    <span>Sex:&nbsp;</span>
</td>
<td>
    <span id="Sex_PDLabel" runat=server></span>
</td>
```

how i can call this return value in my code?
i want to get corresponding value to any variable. so try to write code something like this:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.Handler, Page), GetType(Page), "GetSEx", "GetSex()", True)
 Dim SexVAl = Sex_PDLabel.InnerText
```

but my sexVal Always getting empty string.i dont know why? what is the problem with my code?

any help is very appriciable..

Comment: Do you need call the Javascript function and execute code behind method? What control call GetSex()?

Comment: What do you need exactly? Do you want to use result of that function in your asp.net codebehind?

Comment: sir i want to get this return value in my code.

Comment: rocky..exactly i want that..i want to use result of that function in my asp.net code..

Comment: my code means in my asp.net code..

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

aspx:
Create a hidden field to store the value.

```
<input type="hidden" id="txtHidden" runat="server" />
```

javascript code:

```
function GetSex()
{
    var sex = EIDAWebComponent.GetSex();
     alert(sex);
    if(sex == 'M')
        document.getElementById("txtHidden").value=  "Male";
    else if(sex == 'F')
        document.getElementById("txtHidden").value =  "Female";
    else if(sex == 'X')
        document.getElementById("txtHidden").value =  "Unknown";
    else
        document.getElementById("txtHidden").value =  "none";
}
```

Call from ASP.NET code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript((Page)(HttpContext.Current.Handler), 
                  typeof(Page), "GetSex", "GetSex();", true);

String value = txtHidden.Value;
```

Comment: here showing error text' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputHidden'

Comment: @user2510547: I have corrected the answer. check it.

Comment: i am getting empty string

Comment: @user2510547: Added the alert(sex); in GetSex() function. check what you are getting in the alert box.

Comment: @ user2510547: Check this EIDAWebComponent.GetSex(); statement whether it returns value 'M' or 'F' or 'X'.

Comment: that returns M .because am getting male value

Comment: @user2510547: Then have you get 'M' in alert box?

Comment: sir that is not getting ..somthing goes wrong i think..let me check

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches is to store the value in a [hidden field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Add following to your ASP.NET markup:

```
<asp:HiddenField id="hdnField" runat="server" />
```

and call:

```
document.getElementById('<%= hdnField.ClientID %>').value = GetSex();
```

In codebehind the value will be accessible as:

```
var val = hdnField.Value;
```